# What is the duration of the effects that the mysterious serum gives?

Tags: fallout-4

It removes 36000, or 10 radiation a second for 3600 seconds, which would last for an hour, but is that in-game hour, or a real-life hour?

How much time does it give 5 strength and 50 damage resistance?

Answer (score 7):

The mysterious serum, as you've said in the question, removes 10 rads per second for 3600 seconds. This is real-time seconds, not in-game seconds.

See [this post](https://www.google.com/amp/s/amp.reddit.com/r/fo4/comments/4bakkv/mysterious_serum_is_amazing_can_pretty_much/?client=safari):

> Mysterious Serum, which gives you -10 Rads per second for an hour(irl time, unless you fast travel).

As for the strength and damage resistance buffs, [this post](https://m.reddit.com/r/fo4/comments/3t24lg/comment/cx2fsdb) says that it lasts as long as the radiation recovery.

> So does the +strength/damage resist last the full 3,600 seconds?
>
> Yeah, it does.

Comment: What about the strength and damage resistance?

Comment: @TimmyJim Whoops, I overlooked that part of the question. Updated my answer to cover that too.